# Angular component when load data from server is blank for a couple seconds

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm building an angular apps with api calls using httpclient, i don't use any package or plugin for that just httpclient.

Here's my example code in service.ts

```
  getAdminMateriDetail(slug: any) {
    return this._http.get(this.apiURL + 'admin/material/' + slug).pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      shareReplay(1),
      tap(() => console.log('Materi Detail after sharing'))
    )
  }
```

i try to get materi detail from server, and in my component

```
getCurrentMateriDetail() {
    return this.userService.getAdminMateriDetail(this.slug).subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        this.currentMateri = data.data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentMateriDetail();
  }
```

i use that code in every page that needs data from server, but what i get is unexpected result, so when i navigate to component that calls an api and subscribe to that api, my component was blank for a couple seconds, sometime it's fast. I'm new using api calls, so is it normal? or maybe i can improve it to make it fast so user won't see a "blank page"?

I also read about caching, and i found `shareReplay(1)` so i add it to my code but still blank for a couple of second. can someone give me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API calls always takes time. So you need to create loader or something like that. In component template you can do it with `ngIfElse`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loadedData; else loader">
  page content
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loader>Loading...</loader>
```

`shareReplay` used for share result of "cold" ([more info](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)) observable between subscribers. But in your case it's useless, because every call of your function creates new Observable. Example:

```
// Correct usage: 
const myMagicData$ = this._http.get(this.apiURL + 'admin/material/' + slug).pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      shareReplay(1),
      tap(() => console.log('Materi Detail after sharing'))
    );
    
myMagicData$.subscribe();
myMagicData$.subscribe();
```

In example above both subscriptions got same result. Without `shareReplay()` every subscription triggers API call.

Comment: so when i go to page 1 i made api call, then i navigate to page 2 then go to page 1 again it made api call again? because i subscribe it everytime i visit/open that component?

Comment: how can i avoid that? can i use something like localstorage?

Comment: You can add some kind of caching, but this is not good idea honestly. There are lot of method how you can cache a repose of you http request (HttpInterceptors, caching in services). But usually it's not necessary. If you decide to add caching, you should know what simple `shareReplay` in service is not enough for you (because you have dynamic part in url - `slug`).

Comment: i see, so the answer is my apps is normal right? i always think that my apps is sucks because of that. thanks a lot

Comment: so i'll just give user a loader/spinner before their data loads

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, since you are doing an async call:

```
this.userService.getAdminMateriDetail(this.slug).subscribe(
  (data:any) => {
    this.currentMateri = data.data;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
)
```

Here, `this.currentMateri` is null until the server responds (assume it to be between 0.1sec and 1 second). So in your HTML, you have to handle "what to do when `this.currentMateri` is null ?"

To handle this, add `*ngIf="currentMateri"` where you display asynchronous data, and add an other tag (div, or whatever) when `*ngIf="!currentMateri"`, so you will display a loader, or anything...

Comment: i forgot that this.currentMateri is null, thanks. but can i avoid the page being blank?

Comment: As I said, by adding `*ngIf`s

Comment: i'm doing it though, i added somehing like spinner when my data is loading, but i just hope that maybe there is a way to avoid loading, and just give user the data instantly

Comment: This is an asynchronous data. You can't get it instantly. You have to wait for the server to give you the answer before using it. You can see it as a letter sent to a friend. He has to wait for the postman to come before having the letter, he can't get it instantly, even if he is in front of its letterbox...